# iOS: Adding new constraints in a custom view the rely on the view's frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, layoutsubviews

I'm trying to understand when to override `layoutSubviews` versus `updateConstraints`.

I have created a custom view, and that view contains other views. I can't set the constraints for the view's subviews in the custom initializer I have as I don't know the custom view's frame yet.

Currently I have this:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Add new constraints
}
```

Then whenever I add or remove any of the subviews, I call `[self setNeedsLayout];`

Is this the correct way to do this? I am currently recreating the constraints whenever `layoutSubviews` is called. I've heard that `updateConstraints` might be what I want? But I'm not sure as the number of subviews does not remain constant, and thus, the number of constraints will not be constant either.

Comment: Your custom view can have a different number of subviews depending on what's set in the initializer?

Comment: You'd better not mix constraints and frame. Just add constraints for the subviews.

Comment: @slickdaddy That's correct, and the amount of subviews could change later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add constraint when you add the subviews. You may do this for each subview individually, or in a custom method if that can be generalized.

The methods `layoutSubvews` and `updateConstraints` are callbacks, and they are called at specific points in the layout cycle. Especially, they are called multiple times, and that automatically prohibits you from using constraints, because there is a danger of creating constraints more than once.

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) stated, `layoutSubviews` should only be used when

> if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want.

If `layoutSubviews` is called, the current *automatic* layout is done, and adding, removing or modifying constraints might re-trigger the layout process. This might slow-down your app extremely.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints) for `updateConstraints` includes also a clear statement when you should overwrite it:

> Override this method to optimize changes to your constraints.

*Changes to constraints* doesn't mean adding constraints. If you need different constraints for your views for different times, you may [`deactivate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526066-deactivate) unused and [`activate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate) needed constraints at runtime. This could be done in `updateConstraints`.

BTW: The (explicit) call of `setNeedsLayout` is usually unnecessary, especially if you have changed the view hierarchy or the layout constraints.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. In the end, I realized I could change my constraints to not depend on the view's frame, and thus I could add those constraints to the view's initializer.